# Incomprehensible induction from Johnsonbaugh's book.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, proof-explanation

[image: page 193]

How is this a proof by induction? If it is, aren't you supposed to be going from 4.3.3 to 4.3.4? This is an example from Johnsonbaugh's book.

EDIT: The question is:
Find a theta notation in terms of n for the number of times the statement x = x + 1 is executed:

1. i = n
2. while (i ≥ 1) {
3. x = x + 1
4. i = Math.floor(i/2)
5. }

We were able to find the notation if n is a power of 2, easily achievable. However, in other cases, we can see that n is between 2 power of 2s. Thus the equation we see below. However, I'm failing to understand how the demo goes from 4.3.3 to 4.3.4. Why is he supposing 4.3.4? I think I'm misunderstanding a step in the explanation.

Comment: It would improve your question greatly if you could write some *introductory* lines explaining what this is about and where your problem lies

Comment: *"We use induction on $k$ to show that in this case the statement $x=x+1$ is executed $k$ times".* Either this was written by a drunk undergrad or we really are missing information on what this is about.

Comment: True brb I will update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"How is this a proof by induction?" Honestly, I couldn't tell you. Maybe I'm just missing context, but that proof you posted looks absolutely horrendous. I don't even think it's correct. For one thing, it makes no sense to perform induction over the variable $k$ when we are trying to proof a statement for all of $n$. The best I can do to provide my own proof.

**Statement:** For every positive integer $n$ there exists some positive integer $k$ such that $$2^{k-1}\leq n < 2^k$$

**Base Case:**

The statement is clearly true for $n=1$ since for $k=1$
$$2^{1-1}=1\leq 1 < 2=2^1$$

**Induction:**

Now suppose for some positive integer $N$ we have for some $k$
$$2^{k-1}\leq N < 2^k$$

We need to show the statement holds for $N+1$. If $N+1<2^k$
$$2^{k-1}\leq N < N+1< 2^k$$

and we are done. Otherwise $N+1\geq 2^k$ and then 
$$2^k\leq N+1\leq N+N=2N<2*2^k=2^{k+1}$$

so in either case the statement holds for $N+1$.

Thus, by the principle of mathematical induction the statement holds for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: This definitely makes more sense TY